# When making a campaign, how liberal can you get with "homebrewing" in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, campaign-development

## Unsure how far to go.

If you want to make your campaign really interesting, how far can you go in making new monsters, artifacts, and such?

Essentially, should you be able to create entire new subtypes of monsters, such as, for example, adding a Spectral Subtype to the Undead Type? Create new deities? Boss monsters who are Legendary but nobody has ever heard of? And should you be able to create new weapons with completely new traits? This is my first time creating one and I'm not quite sure how crazy I can go with it.

Comment: I'm torn between "this is a discussion prompt" and "someone could write up a *really* good experience-based answer that describes what *challenges* different types of/extents of homebrewing present." Stackizens: I really hope we see some of the latter; many of the former would argue that the question itself is too broad or unfocused.

Comment: Hi @TheCentaur and welcome--like my comment says above, I hope this ends up the sort of question that generates some of our best answers: experience-based, broadly-applicable, well-communicated. If you *do* want to just chat a bit about homebrew please feel free to drop by [chat] or one of the various [forums we recommend](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970).

Comment: Thank you for responding, I hope somebody posts an answer on one of my examples, perhaps the one about Subtypes. I may visit the forums. Thanks again.

Comment: I think it's certainly editable into a form suitable for RPG.SE, but I also think that as written it's an opinion-based discussion prompt. Though I'm not immediately sure how to edit it into a suitable form.

Comment: The question as it stands is straightforward: You can homebrew absolutely anything you want! The game gives at least a little direction on how to create kingdoms and monsters. It might give guidance on creating magic items, I can't clearly remember that one. The real issue is that TheCentaur is just starting out and seemingly wants some guidance. I'd recommend checking the second answer in this article: https://theangrygm.com/ask-angry-advantage-and-first-campaign/ It doesn't explicitly cover creating custom stuff, but it helps provide some hints that lean that direction!

Comment: It's worth asking, is this a campaign you are making for your personal games or one you want to publish on various websites like DM's Guild? The answer would vary based on which.

Comment: I'm not sure yet, but probably just for me. It's my first one, so I don't think it will be that high of quality. I guess it would just be personal. I think this can allow me to answer my own question, so thanks!